# PHP5 Uploader works for all devices but Apple mobile

Tags: php, file

I have this code for a PHP5 uploader.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "cdn/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$file_name =  basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];
$pro_pic = $_SESSION['pro_pic'];
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {

$target_dir = "cdn/uploads/";
    $ext = substr(strrchr($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"], '.'), 1); // extension
    $file_name = md5(mt_rand()) . '.' .$ext; // unique filename
    $targetfile = $target_dir . $file_name;

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $targetfile)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Here's how it works:
 1. You choose an image to upload.
2.The image gets processed through the code in which the image filename will be changed from it's default to a new name via the MD5.
 So if the image name was coolpic.jpg, it would be changed to 3344rt5gggrtgfffs345455gtge445.jpg 
3. Then the post would be uploaded into the CDN.
This works for all devices and computers **EXPECT** iDevices such as iPhones, iPads, etc. 
Why is that and how can I fix it so the uploader will be compatible with all devices including iDevices.

Comment: Nowhere do you ever bother checking if the upload ever succeeded. You simply plough on ahead whether an upload was performed or not. There's a `['error']` parameter in $_FILES, which sould be the **FIRST** thing you ever check before doing anything else.

Comment: You may provide an example. However, I think that IOS have some problems with image uploads, if the problem if not your script, it should be in the device. Did you checked that the request made by the IOS mobile its correct? For be more specific search for file upload opera failures.

Comment: What about chrome? Might be issues with webkit browsers.